# Preserve Colors of a PNG Image inside of a Button and List SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

The colors of the image are changed when it is nested in `List` and `Button` View.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body:some View{
        List{
            Button(action:{}){
                Image("img")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a style `PlainButtonStyle()` to the `Button` preserves the colors of the PNG:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body:some View{
        List{
            Button(action:{}){
                Image("img")
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [rendering mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269728-renderingmode) to original to avoid the blue tint by default that appears on any view that is a [Swift UI Button](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button)

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body:some View{
        List{
            Button(action:{}){
                Image("img")
                  .renderingMode(.original)
            }
        }
    }
}
```