# Can't remove accent color of button without breaking functionality

Tags: swiftui

```
 Button{
            print("hi")
          }label:{
            Image(systemName: "applelogo")
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
              .padding()
              .background(.clear)
              .cornerRadius(15)
              .overlay(
                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                      .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2)
              )
          }
```

So I have this button and I tried to add the renderingMode modifier with .original but that did nothing, adding a plain button style fixes the color issue but then the functionality of the button is broken and I still want the default button animation that it has anyways, any ideas? Not sure why renderingMode(.original) isn't working.

Comment: What, exactly, would you think `.renderingMode(.original)` is going to do on the button? Besides the fact it was deprecated after macOS 10.13, it applied to fonts. What "color issue" are you having with this button?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/renderingmode(_:) it's deprecated? I don't see that anywhere neither do I see anything about fonts the Apple docs state its for images. By default SwiftUI is making my button image the accent color(blue) no matter what the actual image color is, I just want the original image color instead of the blue accent color. There are many posts like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229416/preserve-colors-of-a-png-image-inside-of-a-button-and-list-swiftui where people mention renderingMode as a fix but that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the `Button`:

The simplest, and Apple recommended, way of changing the symbol color is simply with `.tint()` like this:

```
    Button{
        print("hi")
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "applelogo")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .background(.clear)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2)
            )
            
    }
    .tint(.green)
```

[image]

If you want to make the `SFSymbol` in the `Button` to ignore the `Button` color, regardless of whether it is the default, or you set it with `.tint()`, you do use `.renderingMode(.original)` on the symbol. However, this ONLY works when the SFSymbol has its own color. "applelogo" is monochrome, so it has no intrinsic color, so `.renderingMode(.original)` has no effect. However, if you do the same thing with a multicolor SFSymbol, it will work.

```
    VStack {
        Button{
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "applelogo")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(.clear)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                )
                
        }
        Button{
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.plus")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(.clear)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                )
        }
    }
    .tint(.purple)
```

[image]

Comment: This does work but the only problem is I would be hardcoding it in that case, I just want to use the default colors for the icon instead of having to hardcode it myself. Do you have any ideas for how I might be able to do something like that?

Comment: I think we are talking about 2 different things. I was thinking of the Button color. You wanted the SFSymbol color. Yes, `.renderingMode()` is correct. See the edits.